# Problem with applying jQuery to an element which has been created by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
$("#ticker-wrapper").rssfeed("http://news.hse.gov.uk/feed/", {
    limit: 5,
    linktarget: '_blank',
    titletag: 'p',
    snippet: false,
    header: false,
    date: false,
    content: false
});

$('#js-news').ticker({
    controls: false,
    titleText: ''
});
```

Basically, a rssfeed is placed inside the wrapper, I then want .ticker to add a ticker effect to the items pulled through by the .rssfeed.

The problem seems to be that the .rssfeed creates the id #js-news (which is where I want to apply the .ticker). Then it seems the .ticker gets fired before #js-news has been created. Effectively it seems to be trying to apply .ticker to the element which hasn't yet been created which then results in nothing appearing.

I've been looking into jQuery .live() and I can get all the code working on a click command. But I need to create the rss feed and apply the ticker when the page loads. Not quite sure what to do?

------ Edit ------

ah ha!

Seems it works now I've moved the main .rssfeed bulk into the html (out of the .ready) and rewriting the ticker code:

```
var tickerTryCount = 0;
function addTicker() {
if (tickerTryCount < 5) {
    if ($('#js-news').size() > 0) {
        $('#js-news').ticker({
            controls: false,
            titleText: ''
        });
    } else {
        tickerTryCount++;
        setTimeout(addTicker, 1000);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Which plugin do you use? Maybe you can set a callback...

Comment: Ya, what is the rssfeed method doing?  Which plugin is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah ha!

Seems it works now I've moved the main .rssfeed bulk into the html (out of the .ready) and rewriting the ticker code:

```
var tickerTryCount = 0;
function addTicker() {
if (tickerTryCount < 5) {
if ($('#js-news').size() > 0) {
    $('#js-news').ticker({
        controls: false,
        titleText: ''
    });
} else {
    tickerTryCount++;
    setTimeout(addTicker, 1000);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Noone likes obtrusive javascript :(  I would look into a 'nicer' way of pulling this off

Answer (score 1):

Call the ticker() on ajaxStop()

```
$("#ticker-wrapper")
    .rssfeed("http://news.hse.gov.uk/feed/", {
        limit: 5,
        linktarget: '_blank',
        titletag: 'p',
        snippet: false,
        header: false,
        date: false,
        content: false
    })
.ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#js-news').ticker({controls: false, titleText: '' });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! Although, testing the code it doesn't seem to work. I've edited my original question with a long winded way to do it at the moment. But I'm currently looking more into .ajaxStop (never used that before).